# Is it possible to put a block inside another block in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

Basically I want to insert two blocks within a bigger block. I've tried doing this:

```
\begin{block}{heading}
    \begin{block}{heading1}
     content
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{heading1}
     content
    \end{block}
\end{block}
```

but it doesn't work. The error message is :

> File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.

I would like to add that this is the first time I've used the LaTeX language, so I'm basically a *noob* here =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Blocks within blocks work best if you box them, since it gives you better control over their width and placement. This is easily achieved using `minipage`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{heading}
    Some filler text

    \hspace*{.1\linewidth}\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{heading 1}
      content
    \end{block}
    \end{minipage}
    \medskip

    Some more filler text

    \hspace*{.1\linewidth}\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{heading 2}
      content
    \end{block}
    \end{minipage}
    \medskip

    Some more filler text
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since `minipage`s tend to remove the appropriate paragraph skipping (above and below), an additional `\medskip` makes the separation more consistent. I've also added an indent of `.1\linewidth`, which technically centers the nested `block` since it's `.8\linewidth` wide.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect such a quick reponse. It works perfectly fine!! Many thanks Werner!!

Comment: I am not so sure of the boxing being required – your example as well as the OPs MWE both compile fine even if one removes the minipages. (For proper indenting they are necessary anyway, but that is another point).